# Show specific events every year

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to show some events every year. E.g
Like birhday, holiaday. which come every year on  a specifc date
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to generate the recurring dates on the client side or server side or are to open to either? If server side, then which framework are you using there?

Comment: Where's the question? Any code you already made? What are you using or willing to use to achieve this?

Comment: actually  i want to show the birthday dates of the facebook in the full calender. But the problem is they are showed on calender on specific date. They should be shown every year.
thanks for the quick respnse.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction is to make a function. Add an object literal boolean to your event data like holiday:

```
 {                   
        "id": "1",
        "title": "All Day Event ", 
        "allDay": "true",
        "start": "1283378679",
        "end": null,
        "url": "#",
        "holiday": "true"
    },
```

then, if ( event.holiday === true ) { event.start = 2010-09-10

You'll have to figure out the formatting but that might work.